# How to specify auto-generated resource files to Qmake?

Tags: qt, resources, qt4, qmake

I have a Qt project with a german translation, `Translation_de.ts`, which is automatically compiled into `Translation_de.qm` via Qmake:

```
TRANSLATIONS += Translation_de.ts
...
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += lrelease
lrelease.input         = TRANSLATIONS
lrelease.output        = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
lrelease.commands      = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/lrelease ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -qm ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
lrelease.CONFIG       += no_link target_predeps
```

The generated `Translation_de.qm` is then compiled into the final application as a resource:

```
RESOURCES += Resources.qrc
```

where `Resources.qrc` looks like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource>
    ...
    <file>Translation_de.qm</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

All of this works fine, except that the very first call to Qmake on a fresh checkout throws the following annoying warning:

```
RCC: Error in 'Resources.qrc': Cannot find file 'Translation_de.qm'
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I correctly specify an auto-generated resource file like `Translation_de.qm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the generated files in qmake phase with e.g. `system(lrelease...)`. Leave the other rules in place too so you don't have to rerun qmake when the input files are changed.

Answer (score 8):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html

CONFIG+=lrelease #generates *.qm files from TRANSLATIONS= to the directory builddir/.qm/
CONFIG+=embed_translations #adds them as qrc resources

so (other than)

```
CONFIG+=lrelease embed_translations
```

no qmake magic is required. Your qm files will be under :/i18n/ unless you specify otherwise with

```
QM_FILES_RESOURCE_PREFIX=/my/customtranslationdirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is just "*ignore_no_exist*" for *lrelease.CONFIG*

As far as I know the *target_predeps* ensures that it is executed before the 'normal' compilation steps are issued. So if it's really only about getting rid of the warning, just add the above given flag. Your qm creation should work once you execute the makefile that was created by the qmake call.

If your qm files are not created try to add:

```
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += compiler_lrelease_make_all
```

Check out this [link](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Custom_tools) for more options that might help you.

Comment: `qmake` will not generate dependencies to files it can not find. The resulting Makefile will fail parallel building.

Comment: you link is dead.